# How to set bash script parameter to file minus the extension

Tags: linux, bash, slurm

so I have this bash file called `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash -l
out_file=`basename "$0"`
#SBATCH --gpus=1
#SBATCH -p long
#SBATCH -o err_${out_file::-3}.out
```

and I want to output the error to `err_test.out`, which is what I'm trying to do in the above file, but it's giving an error. Doesn't like the `=` how can I set the output file to the file name I specified.

Comment: "_it's giving an error_" - do we have to guess or will you add it to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
out_file=$(basename "$0")
echo sbatch --gpus=1 -p long -o "err_${out_file%.*}.out"
```

If that outputs the `sbatch` command you're trying for, then remove the `echo` and give it a try.

A couple of comments:

- 99% of the time you don't want a shell that's running your script to behave as a login shell, so I removed the `-l` option from the top line.
- The `$( ... )` method of capturing the output of a command is usually better than the old-style method that uses backticks/backquotes.  There are many fewer problems with special characters and nesting one capture within another.
- You had the right idea about how to strip trailing characters from the `$out_file` variable, I was lazy and didn't test your expression, instead I replaced it with one I use a lot, and is somewhat simpler.

Comment: much appreciated!

Comment: hmmm apologies I gave the accepted answer before testing it. Put this in the bash script

!/bin/bash -l
out_file=$(basename "$0")
#SBATCH --gpus=1
#SBATCH -p long
#SBATCH -o "err_${out_file%.*}.out" and it didn't output to that file for some reason. Echo printed out the correct string, but it's not outputting to that file. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to tell `basename` the suffix. But, having a `.sh` suffix to a file name is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Gooby I don't understand how you intend the `#SBATCH` lines in your script to work.  They don't match up to how a shell script functions except as a way to comment out (disable) lines, and that appears to be why it doesn't work when you try to use them.  Can you explain what you're trying to do with them?  Are you hoping to use multiple lines of the script to create the full `sbatch` command?

Comment: sorry I'm not super familiar with slurm and Linux this is just how I've seen others in my lab sbatch a slurm job. I don't even know what `#SBATCH` does exactly.

Comment: @Gooby How well does my answer work if you do as I suggested and remove the `echo` word from the third line?

Comment: it creates an out file called `slurm-373811.out`, which is just slurm then the job Id. Apologies again for unchecking your answer as the answer. I don't want to confuse others who may look at this question. But I'm sure together we can find the correct answer.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor "basename the suffix?" I don't know what you mean.

Comment: read the manual for `basename` focus on the bit that mentions suffix: “Print  NAME with any leading directory components removed.  If specified, also remove a trailing SUFFIX.”